# ZipCode Query to pull Five and Nine Digits

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull a query in MSSQL to pull the if they exist 9 digits zipcodes out of the cus_address table. I am already pulling 5 digit zipcodes out of a table i created myself called dbo.WEST_PALM_ZIPS. I need to pull all the zips in my WEST_PALM_ZIPS table as well as the CUS_ADDRESS.POSTAL_CODE (any help is appreciated)

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Member Id] = Cust.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID,[FirstName] = Cust.First_Name    

[Lastname] = Cust.Last_Name,

[Email] = Cust.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS,

[Zip Code] = addr.POSTAL_CODE

FROM ORDER_DETAIL OD
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER  Cust 
    ON  Cust.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and Cust.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and od.subsystem = 'MBR'

INNER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS  Addr    
    ON Addr.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_ID  
    and Addr.POSTAL_CODE in ( select POSTAL_CODE from [dbo].[WEST_PALM_ZIPS])
    and Addr.COUNTRY_descr = 'United States'
    and  If(Len([Postal_Code])>5,Left([Postal_Code],5) & "-" &
Mid([Postal_Code],6),[Postal_Code])][0-9]


INNER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS_DETAIL  AddrD 
    ON AddrD.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and AddrD.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and AddrD.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_ID 
    and AddrD.ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE
```

Comment: the `IF(LEN...)`, `Mid(`, `& "-" &` doesn't look like SQL Server

Comment: For non-US readers it seems the 9 digit zip is 10 characters - 5 digits, a hyphen, then four digits: http://sanjaal.com/java/627/java-regular-expressions/us-5-and-9-digits-zip-code-validation-in-java-using-regular-expressions/

Comment: I think LEFT might be more acceptable, thoughts @Lamak?

Comment: Well, there are too many things that won't work on SQL Server. You can't use `if()` like that, you need to use a `CASE` expression. There's no `Mid()` function, `&` isn't used to concatenate strings, `"-"` needs to use single quotes instead of double quotes, I don't even understand what the `[0-9]` is doing, but it definitely doesn't work on SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak I assume Shawn was using an excel-worksheet-function-like pseudo-code to demonstrate the logic he's after; i.e. that code doesn't run in SQL but he'd like it translated to something that does.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Yup, didn't really understand the question at first, but upvoted your answer now that I do get what op was asking

Comment: @ShawnRahmani FYI: `Mid` don't exist in SQL (MS T-SQL): the equivalent is `substring`.  `&` should be replaced by `+`.  I assume the `[0-9]` means you only want numeric digits (aside from the hyphen) - for that use the `like` statement with pattern matching (per my example below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after - though please shout if I've misunderstood anything / if it doesn't work as you'd expected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Member Id] = Cust.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
,[FirstName] = Cust.First_Name    
,[Lastname] = Cust.Last_Name
,[Email] = Cust.PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDRESS
,[Zip Code] = addr.POSTAL_CODE
FROM ORDER_DETAIL OD

INNER JOIN CUSTOMER  Cust 
    ON  Cust.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and Cust.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and od.subsystem = 'MBR'

INNER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS  Addr    
    ON Addr.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_ID  
    and Addr.COUNTRY_descr = 'United States'
    --check for 5 digit or 9 digit zip codes
    and 
    (
        --check for 5 digit zip codes based on contents of table
        (
            LEN(Addr.POSTAL_CODE) = 5
            and Addr.POSTAL_CODE in 
            ( 
                select POSTAL_CODE 
                from [dbo].[WEST_PALM_ZIPS] wpz
                --if you want to be sure you only get the 5 digit codes from this table (though from your description I believe that's all this table contains?)
                --where LEN(POSTAL_CODE) = 5
                --and Addr.POSTAL_CODE like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            )
        )
        or -- check that it's a 9 digit code
        (
            LEN(Addr.POSTAL_CODE) = 10
            and SUBSTRING(Addr.POSTAL_CODE,6,1) = '-'   
            and Addr.POSTAL_CODE like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
        )
    )
INNER JOIN CUS_ADDRESS_DETAIL  AddrD 
    ON AddrD.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and AddrD.SUB_CUSTOMER_ID = OD.SHIP_SUB_CUSTOMER_ID 
    and AddrD.CUS_ADDRESS_ID = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_ID 
    and AddrD.ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE = OD.SHIP_ADDRESS_TYPE_CODE
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx for an explanation of the like statement / pattern matching used in the above example.